# Get the last subscription renewal order information in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, woocommerce-subscriptions

We are trying to pass woocommerce subscription renewal data to a loyalty rewards program and are having all kinds of issues and have been unable to get relevant woocommerce subscription information or anything to work. Our full loyalty code for zinrelo works with manual data.

FUll code with your suggestions runs in functions file

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_renewal_payment_complete', 'custom_add_subscription_points', 10, 1 );
  function custom_add_subscription_points( $subscription ) {
    if ( ! $subscription )
        return;

    // Get related orders
    $orders_ids = $subscription->get_related_orders();

    // Get the last renewal related Order ID
    $order_id = reset( $order_ids );

    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);
    $order_id = $order->get_id();
    $order_email = $order->get_billing_email();
    $order_date = $order->get_date_completed();
    $order_total = $order->get_total();
    $order_subtotal = $order->get_subtotal();

    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.zinrelo.com/v1/loyalty/purchase");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user_email={$order_email}&activity_id=made_a_purchase&order_{id=$order_id}&total={$order_total}&subtotal={$order_subtotal}");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    $headers = array();
    $headers[] = "Partner-Id: 000000";
    $headers[] = "Api-Key: 000000";
    $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    if (curl_errno($ch)) {
    echo 'Error:' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    curl_close ($ch);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As `WC_Subscription` [`get_related_orders()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/subscriptions/develop/functions/#section-17) method gives an array of order IDs, you need to use [`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) function, to get the last renewal order ID and avoid an error with [`wc_get_order()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-function-wc_get_order.html#71-86) funtion that expect a unique order ID as argument *(but not an array)*.

So try:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_subscription_renewal_payment_complete', 'custom_add_subscription_points', 10, 1 );
function custom_add_subscription_points( $subscription, $last_order ) {
    if ( ! $subscription )
        return;

    $order_email    = $last_order->get_billing_email();
    $order_date     = $last_order->get_date_completed();
    $order_total    = $last_order->get_total();
    $order_subtotal = $last_order->get_subtotal();
}
```

It should work now with:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, "user_email={$order_email}&activity_id=made_a_purchase&order_{id=$order_id}&total={$order_total}&subtotal={$order_subtotal}");
```

Comment: When a renewal runs we get a 500 error. Any thoughts

Comment: I added our full functions code able. The curl code when created manually and opend in a php file works.

Comment: @MarkFerguson Yes my code works… but I can't test the CURL Part and nobody can.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec a code typo, `{id=$order_id}` should be `id={$order_id}`